# What is the smallest resistance that can be used in a 5 V circuit if the resistors available are rated for 1/4 W?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

> What is the smallest resistance that can be used in a 5 V circuit if the resistors available are rated for 1/4 W?

What is *kind* of throwing me is that it wants the "*smallest* resistance that can be used.", makes me think I need some type of range of numbers but there was nothing in the problem that gave me the tolerance of the resistor so not sure about that. Anyway, what I did instead was rearrange $P = IV$ to $P = \frac{V^{2}}{R}$, then plugged in the values $5\text{ V}$ and $0.25\text{ W}$ and got $100\text{ ohms}$. Is this right? $100\text{ ohms}$ is the smallest resistance that can be used here?

Comment: Hi Cosmo Cosmo - actually, we do mind. We'd much prefer that you only ask one question per post. Accordingly, I've edited the second question out of your post. Besides that, however, questions like this where you're just asking for someone to check your work are off topic here. This is really a site for conceptual questions.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize that. Will try and remove the problem then.

Comment: That's a poorly phrased question, because you can make the smallest resistance as small as you like, you will simple need more resistors in series and in parallel to make a compound resistor with higher power rating. That's an often used approach to make circuits more reliable. Even if one resistor fails, the total resistance doesn't vary from zero (for a short) to infinity (for an open) but only by a fraction of the design resistance. Having said that, that's not what the naive question wants you to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the smallest resistance that can be used in a 5 V circuit if
>   the resistors available are rated for 1/4 W?

This is a *trick* question of sorts.  It's true that one could work from the relationship

$$p_R = \frac{v^2_R}{R}$$

and the range of $R$ for which $p_R \le 0.25W$.

However, this completely ignores the issue of [derating for reliability](http://www.navsea.navy.mil/nswc/crane/sd18/Pages/Resistors/ResistorsDerating.aspx). [image]

No seasoned EE would use a resistor of a particular power rating in a circuit where it is required to operate at its rated maximum power on average.

Having said that, your approach is correct but I'd like to pose the question more realistically:

- If there is 5V across a resistor, what is the minimum resistor value
  such that the power dissipated is no more than 1/4W?

From this problem statement, it follows that

$$R \ge \frac{(5V)^2}{0.25W} = 100\Omega $$

Your approach on the 2nd problem is also correct.

Comment: I edited the question, if you'd like to update your answer accordingly.